# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un print en un bucle for y que me aparezca sin saltos de línea?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer un print en un bucle for sin los saltos de línea. En Python.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de incluir el código que has intentado o que te da problemas. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta depende de la versión de python que estes usando.
Si estás usando python2 tienes que poner una coma al final de la impresión:

```
print "tu mensaje",
```

En cambio, en python3 tendrías que establecer el parámetro por defecto "end" a una cadena vacía o a un espacio:

```
print("tu mensaje", end='')
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás utilizando Python 3.x, será tan sencillo como modificar el parámetro 'end' que por defecto es un salto de línea '\n'

```
print("Mi mensaje", end='\n') # Imprime un salto de linea al final
```

Se puede modificar para que la línea termine como uno lo desee. Por ejemplo:

```
print("Mi mensaje", end='') # No imprime nada al final
print("Mi mensaje", end='\t') # Imprime una tabulacion al final
```

Ahí se puede seguir traveseando un poco más.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Configurando el `end` en el print puedes establecer el separador, que por defecto es un salto de línea `\n`.

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

for x in fruits:
  print(x) 

for x in fruits:
  print(x, end=" ")
```

Con resultado:

```
$ python script.py

apple
banana
cherry

apple banana cherry
```